# How does this modernizr/jQuery image rotator works?

Tags: jquery, html, modernizr

I will probably get negative points due to my kind of question but here it goes. I'm very interested in this modern design over at [www.bungie.net](http://www.bungie.net). The semi full-screen slider it's amazing and I would like to know how it works. I do know it uses modernizr and not too sure jquery but can anyone tell me how.

Comment: at least he/she knew the negative points were coming, btw it wasn't me who down voted but I'm glad you at least recognized in advance.  it looks as if this code has been minified and you only have some parts - but the gist is they are using modernizer to see if browser supports css animation if it does it's using that instead of js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replicate this using just css3 here 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/  here is a supersized jquery plug in as well

you could use the css one and fall back to the other one for all other browsers if your using modernizer it will just be based on whether or not the html tag has a certain class

Comment: np - sometimes you just need someone to point you in the right direction good luck